# bar_index different in PineScript Logs vs Alert

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Why is that when I look at 30S EURUSD Pine Log I see a `bar_index` of 22190 but the same candle reported via a webhook alert shows `bar_index`  of 27851 . Is there a fixed difference between the two methods of displaying `bar_index` ?

Comment: To get an answer, you must share your code. What you tried, or reproduce the unexpected behavior.